# .htaccess - Display content of folder in a subdirectory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

When user visits **domain.com/test/** it should display **domain.com/test/folder/index.php** by default.

```
index.html             <-- current homepage
   /test/              <-- .htaccess file
     /folder/
       index.php
```

Currently I use:

`DirectoryIndex folder/index.php`

But is there any other way? I tried RewriteRule but it won't work:

`RewriteRule ^(.*) /folder/index.php [NC,L,QSA]`

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ folder/index.php`

Comment: @Jeremy I tried this but I get 403 Forbidden error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this rule in `/test/.htaccess`:

```
DirectorySlash Off
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^[^/]*$ folder/index.php [L]
```

Comment: Not sure because there is no 403 causing rule in my answer. Try ` Options +FollowSymLinks +Indexes` on top of your .htaccess and make sure `folder` doesn't have any .htaccess

Comment: Correct! I added: `Options +FollowSymLinks` and it works fine. Can I ask if it is possible to retain the url without redirecting it?

Comment: Yes it doesn't change URL and there is no `R` flag. Let me modify answer.